Too much whitespace in my Julia gif (using Plots.jl)
I'm using Plots.jl to create some animation but the resulting .gif file has too much white space surrounding it.
For example, I took the Lorenz Attractor example directly from the documentation and added the following flags to the first plot3d call, so it looks like:
plt = plot3d(1,
    xlim = (-30, 30), ylim = (-30, 30), zlim = (0, 60),
    legend = false, marker = 2,
    grid=false, xaxis = false, yaxis = false, zaxis = false,
)

The resulting gif has (in my taste) too much white space around it:

I tried to add flags like margin and play a little with the size of the plots but it didn't change a lot... still too much whitespace.
How can I solve it?
